# SQLalchemy trying to connect to postgresql using oop

Tags: python, postgresql, oop, sqlalchemy

I'm trying to teach myself a bit of OOP and as a test i'm trying to create a class that will connect to an existing postgresql database i've created.

I can connect to the database fine using sqlalchemy if I use this code

```
engine = create_engine('postgresql://user@localhost/dbname')
conn = engine.connect()
result = conn.execute(sql)
for row in result:
    print(row)
```

However, as I mentioned i'm new to OOP so trying to figure out how to replicate this in a class format. The following code gives the error `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'execute'`. I imagine there are many errors and best practices i'm missing out on so some kind of guidance would be much appreciated.

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

class dbConnect(object):
    db_connection = None
    db_cur = None

    def __init__(self):
        self.db_connection = create_engine('postgresql://user@localhost/dbname')
        self.cur = self.db_connection.connect()

    def query(self, query):
        test = self.db_cur.execute(query)
        return test

sql = """
SELECT
    id
FROM
    t
WHERE
    id = 14070
"""

x = dbConnect()
result = x.query(sql)
for row in result:
    print(row)
```

Comment: Well, you've assigned `db_cur = None` but you subsequently want to call `.execute(query)` on it.

Comment: Well, that was easy. you're correct and it works now. Thanks. Would still love to know if there are any best practices with this type of thing.

Comment: Best practices with this type of thing are called patterns, so you may want to look into "factory" or "singleton", both of which might be applicable here. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I always use Pajlada's [Database Manager Singleton Class](https://github.com/pajlada/pajbot/blob/master/pajbot/managers/db.py). It's pretty easy to get going. All you need to do is initialize the class with your URL.

```
DBManager.init('psqlurlhere')
```

and then whenever you want to create a session there are multiple ways to do it:

Create a session that will end after you do certain thing

```
with DBManager.create_session_scope() as session:
    session.add(Model)
    session.commit()
```

Create a session that you will reuse throughout your program:

```
session = DBManager.create_session(expire_on_commit=False)
session.add(Model)
session.comit()
```